# LINQ - Left Join converting RIGHT results to List

Tags: c#, linq, left-join, grouping

I'm struggling to find the correct combination of LINQ Methods to perform a multi-table left join with a one to many mapping that makes a list along with the grouped results.

**Current Status**
I have a Plan table, joined with other tables to get the columns I need to get my list of plans.

```
var plans = await (
                        from ubp in db.ViewUserBusinessPlan
                        join bp in db.ViewBusinessPlan on ubp.BusinessPlanId equals bp.BusinessPlanId
                        where bp.BusinessId == businessId
                        select new
                        {
                            ubp.UserBusinessPlanId,
                            ubp.BusinessPlanId,
                            bp.Name,
                            bp.PlanGroup,
                            bp.BusinessId,
                            ubp.BusinessLocationId,
                            ubp.StripeSubscriptionId,
                            ubp.UserId,
                            ubp.BusinessPlanPriceCents
                        }
```

**Problem:**
Now I need to ultimately get the applicable Tax Rates that are associated with those Plans. This is stored in 2 tables.

1. UserBusinessPlanTaxRates - (a mapping table) that contains UserBusinessPlanId and TaxRateId.
2. TaxRates - TaxRate Information with TaxRateId as PK

Some plans have tax rates, some do not, so need a LEFT JOIN type scenario. Also, some plans can have multiple tax rates so I need a list of TaxRates. I've tried various Group methods, subqueries, and left joins. But nothing seems to put them all together.

I want to get all plans, with a list of TaxRates.

Comment: there are three cases 1) A & B 2) A Only 3) B Only.   A Left Outer Join will get only 1 & 2,  To get 3 you need to reverse order of A & B in the Left Outer Join (really a Right Outer Join).

Comment: I'm sorry, @jdweng I'm not following. What are A, B, and C?

Comment: What LINQ are you using? LINQ to SQL / EF / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x?

Comment: In your case they are udp and bp in the c# code.

Comment: @NetMage, I'm using LinqToDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a sub-query in the `select` to do the necessary join:

```
TaxRates = db.UserBusinessPlanTaxRates.Where(ubptr => ubptr.UserBusinessPlanId == ubp.UserBusinessPlanId)
                                      .GroupJoin(db.TaxRates, ubptr => ubptr.TaxRateId, tr => tr.TaxRateId, (ubptr, trj) => trj)
                                      .SelectMany(trj => trj)
                                      .ToList()
```

Whether it will translate properly (or optimally) to SQL depends on what LINQ to database you are using.

Comment: I'm using LinqToDB. This seems to make sense, and it compiles. But at runtime it blows up with: `Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Wrong subQuery argument.'`

Comment: Sounds like you are using .Net Core? Perhaps try putting `.AsEnumerable()` before `GroupJoin(`.